# How to create ActionScript 2 project in FlashDevelop

Tags: flash, actionscript

In the latest FlashDevelop (FlashDevelop 5.3.0 at this time), by default you can only create ActionScript 3 project. But sometime you need ActionScript 2 project (for CryEngine 5.4).

I see some topic like: 
[How to enable ActionScript 2?](http://www.flashdevelop.org/community/viewtopic.php?f=13&t=10393) that's so outdated, lead you to [broken link](http://flashdevelop.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/FD4/External/Extensions/AS2Templates/AS2Templates-1.01.fdz) or [topic that](http://www.flashdevelop.org/community/viewtopic.php?f=13&t=12963) requests re-upload for the broken link that no-one bothers answer :D (Nah, not important, just list out for a laugh)

I create this question for the sake of CryEngine 5.4's users then. So how to create ActionScript 2 project in FlashDevelop?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Interesting enough, you don't need to go around the internet to find your answer, the solution is right inside FlashDevelop: Plug-in.

Step 1: Go to `Tools` > `Install Software...`
[image: <code>Tools</code> > <code>Install Software...</code>]

Step 2: You should see `AS2 Templates` by now. Install it.
[image: <code>AS2 Templates</code>]
After install successfully, FlashDevelop should open a new FlashDevelop window for you (you do know that after install any plug-in, you need to restart the app to take effect, right? This app automatically start a new window to take effect, cool)

Step 3: Go to `Project` > `New project...` and Enjoy!
[image]

Answer (score 0):

FlashDevelop's Install Software menu doesn't seem to work anymore. Fortunately, the FlashDevelop GitHub is still up, and I managed to find [a link](https://raw.github.com/fdorg/flashdevelop/development/External/Extensions/AS2Templates/AS2Templates-1.01.fdz) to download the legacy templates. Download the file and open it with FlashDevelop. When prompted to extract the file, press "OK." Afterwards, you should be able to create an AS2 project from the new project dialog.